# C# Winforms Get a Form's Stretched Background Image

Tags: c#, image, winforms, stretch

How can I retrieve a form's stretched image? When I use MyForm.BackgroundImage it gives me the original image, but not the stretched image that is being displayed on the form.

If I cannot get the image, can I recreate the resulting image from BackgroundImageLayout = Stretch?

Why I want to do this:
I have a control that does not allow transparency. In order to fake transparency I take the background image and create an image for the section that the control covers. This works well until I set the BackGroundImageLayout to anything other than none.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just stretch it yourself the same way, use the form's ClientSize property and the Graphics.DrawImage() overload that takes Rectangle.  Might as well use that stretched image for the BackgroundImage as well, and pick the 32bppPArgb pixel format, makes the UI a lot smoother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve/re-create the stretched form background image like so:

```
    private Bitmap getFormBackgroundImage()
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.DrawImage(this.BackgroundImage,
                new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

Then you can crop a portion of it to use as the child control's background.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

a) Set the background image of the form (Base Control).

```
this.BackgroundImage = <image>;
```

b) Create a child control and drop it over over your base control.

c) Set the dock of your child control to Fill.

```
this.childControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

d) In the base control constructor , set the background image for the child control as the image of the base control. Like this:

```
childControl.BackgroundImage = this.BackgroundImage;
```

e) Set the background image layout of the child control to strech.

```
childControl.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

This would make your child control appear as transparent. Hope it solves your problem.